# window bat to check website and restart coldfusion

Tags: batch-file, coldfusion, wget

I am new to bat script. I want below script to check if web is up and if not restart the coldfusion and save all info into log file.

```
@REM Remove any existing files.
    del C:\Users\Administrator\check.txt

    @REM to download file
    wget -O check.txt --no-check-certificate https://10.2.3.30/ebanking/ch/en-en/index.cfm

    @REM Search for the term in the previously downloaded file.

    FINDSTR  /C:"index.cfm" check.txt
    if errorlevel equ 1  notfound
    found
    cls


    :notfound

    echo notfound > log.txt
    echo stopping ebanking >> log.txt
    call  C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\bin\cfstop.bat  

    echo starting ebanking >> log.txt
    call  C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\bin\cfstart.bat
    cls
    exit

    :found
    echo found >> log.txt

    cls
    exit
```

Comment: Unless you want this question closed as `unclear what you're asking` edit the question and specify what is the problem and make sure the description is detailed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed `goto` command for the label `notfound`. For logic, I swapped label between notfound/found

```
@echo off

pushd "C:\Users\Administrator"

@REM Remove any existing files.
del check.txt

@REM to download file
wget -O check.txt --no-check-certificate https://10.2.3.30/ebanking/ch/en-en/index.cfm

@REM Search for the term in the previously downloaded file.

FINDSTR  /C:"index.cfm" check.txt
if errorlevel equ 1 (goto notfound)

:found
echo found >> log.txt
exit /b 0

:notfound
echo notfound > log.txt
echo stopping ebanking >> log.txt
call  C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\bin\cfstop.bat  

echo starting ebanking >> log.txt
call  C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\bin\cfstart.bat
exit
```

---

you could simplify the code to the following in a loop

```
@echo off
set "someurl=https://10.2.3.30/ebanking/ch/en-en/index.cfm"
:loop
wget --server-response -nv --spider %someurl% 2>&1 | find "HTTP/1.1 200 OK">nul
if errorlevel 1 (
  echo %DATE% %TIME%: stopping ebanking>> log.txt
  call  C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\bin\cfstop.bat
  timeout 5>nul
  echo %DATE% %TIME%: starting ebanking>> log.txt
  call  C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\bin\cfstart.bat
) else (
  echo %DATE% %TIME%: site is up>> log.txt
)
rem Wait 1 hour before loop
timeout 3600
goto loop
```

Comment: Many Thanks. With little adjustment, it meet my needs.